# Properties of a continuous function that satisfies $f(tx)=t^2 f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) > 0$ for each $x \neq 0$ e, moreover,
>   $$f(tx)=t^2 f(x)$$
>   for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> (i) Determine $f(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.
>
> (ii) Show that there is $C,D>0$ such that
>   $$C\Vert x \Vert^2 \leq f(x) \leq D\Vert x \Vert^2$$
>   for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.
>
> (iii) Is $f$ differentiable at $0$?

**My attempt.**

(i) Fix $x\neq 0$ and define $\varphi(t) = f(tx) =t^2f(x) = \alpha t^2$. So, $\varphi$ is a continuous function and $\varphi(\mathbb{R}) = [0,\infty)$ by Intermediate Value Theorem. Thus, $f(\mathbb{R}^n) = [0,\infty)$.

(ii) We have $f(x) = f\left(|x|\frac{x}{|x|}\right) = |x|^2f\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right)$. We know that $S^{n-1}$ is compact, $f(S^{n-1})$ has a maximum and minimum, respectively, $D$ and $C$. Therefore,
$$C|x|^2 \leq f(x) \leq D|x|^2.$$

(iii) Since $C|x|^2 \leq f(x) \leq D|x|^2$,
$$C|x| \leq \frac{f(x)}{|x|} \leq D|x|,$$
then
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{|h|} & = & \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}{|h|}\\
& = & 0\\
& = & Df_{0}(h) 
\end{eqnarray*},$$
that is, $f$ is differentiable and $Df_{0} \equiv 0$.

---

Is correct? Im not sure about (i).

Comment: Seems all correct to me! Well done!

Comment: @Shashi thank you!

Comment: Your work is fine, but there is a shortcut: note that $f(t) = f(t \cdot 1) = t^2f(1)$. Therefore this function is just $f(x) = ax^2$ for some $a > 0$.